# cloudformation- how to use Ref in sources of AWS::CloudFormation::Init section?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to write sources inside `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` to take a parameter like below :

```
"Parameters" : {
    "Environment" : {
            "Description" : "The Environment",
            "Type" : "String",
            "AllowedValues" : [
                "DEV",
                "QA",
                "UAT",
                "PROD"
            ]
        }
}
```

Below is my Metadata section :

```
"LaunchTemplate": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate",
        "Metadata": {
            "Comment" : "Install application",
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                    "configSets" : {
                        "full_install" : [ "prepare", "app-deployment" ]
                    },
            "app-deployment" : {
                    "sources": {
                        "Fn::Join":["",["/app/",{"Ref": "Environment"},"/appname"]] : "https://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/appname.tar"
                    },
                    "files": {
                        "Fn::Join":["",["/opt/",{"Ref": "Environment"},"/index.html"]] : {
                    "content" : "<html><title>HelloTitle</title><body><h1>header H1</h1></body></html>"
                }
```

This is not working. 
Can I user `Ref` function to use parameter this way inside `sources` and `files` section??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.

However, the **workaround** would be to use to use [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-commands) section.

I can **demonstrate the idea** behind the workaround  using `yaml` (its what I personal use) including **multiline** files:

```
commands: 

  04_setup_index_html:
    command: !Sub |
      mkdir -p /opt/${Environment}

      echo "<html><title>HelloTitle</title><body><h1>header H1</h1></body></html>" \
        > /opt/${Environment}/index.html

  05_setup_index2_html_multiline:
    command: !Sub |
      mkdir -p /opt/${Environment}

      cat >/opt/${Environment}/index2.html << EOL
      <html>
          <title>HelloTitle</title>
          <body>
            <h1>header H1</h1>
          </body>
      </html>
      EOL
```

This way you can create your files and folders dynamically based on the template `Parameters`.

Same of course would be possible in `json`, but I don't have a tested working example right now. The snipped in `yaml` provided works for sure.

Comment: Thank you :)  i'll use commands to move the files after copying them in generic folder